# Using the .get Method within a called function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I created a Window in tkinter with a button, and entryfield and a combobox. When the button is clicked a function is called which ".get"s the entry and changes the list for the combobox (via sql request).

the issue seems to be with the paramteters given from one function/class to the other function.

I tried a few combinations and googled but without success. Currently this error appears:

```
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'Ent_first_name_MA'
```

(Without the `"Win_MA_Sel"` part in the `"Func_Updated_Ma"` function it also doesnt work. I also tried `"Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win.Ent_first_name_MA.get()"` but it didnt work as well.)

Here the code, there is more but I would guess this is the important part:

```
    def Func_Show_MA(self):
        global Cockpit_Win
        Cockpit_Win.withdraw()#.deiconify() to show again
        Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win = Toplevel() 
        Class_MA_Win(Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win, Cockpit_Win) 


    class Class_MA_Win(): 

        def __init__(self, Win_MA_Sel, Cockpit_Win):  

            self.Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win = Win_MA_Sel
            self.Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win.title("Mitarbeiter auswählen")

            Ent_first_name_MA = Entry(self.Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win) #Vorname
            Ent_first_name_MA.grid(column=2, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=0, pady=10)

            Btt_Update_MA = Button(self.Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win, text="Liste Updaten", command = lambda: self.Func_Update_MA(Win_MA_Sel))
            Btt_Update_MA.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=10, pady=10)

        def Func_Update_MA(self, Win_MA_Sel):
            Entry_name = Win_MA_Sel.Ent_first_name_MA.get()
            Entry_lastname = Win_MA_Sel.Ent_last_name_MA.get()
            Entry_ID = Win_MA_Sel.Ent_ID_MA.get()

Cockpit_Win = Tk()

#Modify the Window
Cockpit_Win.title("Ressourcen Verwaltung")
Cockpit_Win.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

Btt_Show_MA = Button(Cockpit_Win, text="Mitarbeiter", width=35,command = lambda: self.Func_Show_MA)
Btt_Show_MA.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, pady=7, sticky=E)

Cockpit_Win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `bind` is wrong.

- Firstly, you do not need a `bind` call to a `Button` widget. It has an in-build `command` option that binds `Left-Mouse-Click` to the button and calls the command.
- Secondly, the `bind` call takes only the `event` argument by default. The function `Func_Update_MA` has no notion of what `Win_MA_Sel` is.

Try something on the following lines:

```
Btt_Update_MA = Button(self.Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win, text = "Liste Updaten", command = lambda: self.Func_Update_MA(Win_MA_Sel))
```

and update the Function definition of `Func_Update_MA` as:

```
def Func_Update_MA(self, Win_MA_Sel)
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds good Iam currently trying it, I assume I can also get rid of the line including the "bind"?
I read somewehere that it would be good convention using the bind, I didnt expect it to cause so much issues. Its maybe better to not use it (at least for a beginner)?

Comment: I updated the initall question accordingly but still get an error. `Toplevel object has no attribute "Ent_first_name_MA"`

Comment: If you are simply re-naming `Win_MA_Sel` to 'Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win', I fail to understand as to why you need another `TopLevel` window. Additionally, you do not need to use `Win_MA_Sel` in any function calls.

Comment: Now, it would also help if you could paste the code of the definition of `Ent_first_name_MA`

Comment: I added the code. Also the new toplevel is because this is the second windwo that openes. So first a window that is called "Cockpit" opens and from there a Button calls a function that closes "Cockpit" and calls the `"Class_MA_Win"`. I added all of the corresponding code.

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure if it is the "correct" solution but since it works, I will go with it for the moment.
If anybody has a better solution feel free to correct me.

Here the code I changed:

```
    Btt_Update_MA = Button(self.Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win, text="Liste Updaten",command = lambda: self.Func_Update_MA(self.Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win, Ent_first_name_MA, Ent_last_name_MA, Ent_ID_MA, Drop_MA))
    Btt_Update_MA.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def Func_Update_MA(self, Mitarbeiter_Selection_Win,Ent_first_name_MA, Ent_last_name_MA, Ent_ID_MA, Drop_MA):
    Entry_name = Ent_first_name_MA.get()
    Entry_lastname = Ent_last_name_MA.get()
    Entry_ID = Ent_ID_MA.get()
```